# Name for this set comparison operator $\frac{|A - B| \cdot |B - A|}{|A \cap B|}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

I'm doing some work on deciding when to combine cliques for data clustering purposes and I've found this distance measure to be useful.

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets.

$\frac{|A - B| \cdot |B - A|}{|A \cap B|}$

It's the number of new edges that would be added if the set of vertices $A \cup B$ were combined into a new clique over the number of vertices appearing in both, original cliques.

It seems possible that this already a familiar distance measure, but I've not run into it before.

Comment: What do you do if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint?

Comment: @CliveNewstead it doesn't arise in my application. I'd be happy to treat  the measure as infinite if they are disjoint.

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch to relate the second term to the Jaccard index, since the whole term after multiplying is just $|A\cup B|$.